# Not sending message on discord bot

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, discord-jda

I am using

- IntelliJ 2020.3.2 Build 203.71487 Community edition
- Java version 15.0.1

I am using maven 15. I have two files first being Main.Java and second being cmds.jav

The imports are there but I didn't add them because I didn't want this to be longer than it had to be
Main.java:

```
public class Main {

    public static String prefix = ";";

    public static void main(String[] args){
        start();
    }
    public static void start(){
        try {

            JDABuilder.create(("Token"), GatewayIntent.GUILD_EMOJIS, GatewayIntent.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, GatewayIntent.DIRECT_MESSAGES, GatewayIntent.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING, GatewayIntent.DIRECT_MESSAGES, GatewayIntent.GUILD_BANS, GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS, GatewayIntent.GUILD_PRESENCES)
                .addEventListeners(new cmds())
                .setStatus(OnlineStatus.DO_NOT_DISTURB)
                .setActivity(Activity.playing("HELP ME"))
                .build();
        }catch (LoginException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

cmds.java:

```
public class cmds extends ListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {

        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");

        if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Main.prefix + "test")) {
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("Hi there!").queue();
        }
    }
}
```

The activity and message work but I can not get the command to work whatsoever. I have watched many videos I was originally using Gradle but I couldn't really get it to work so I started from scratch with maven and tried to follow this guide: https://github.com/dawidekdevelopers/DiscordTutorial

Console:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[main] WARN JDA - Automatically disabled CacheFlags due to missing intents
[main] WARN JDA - Disabled CacheFlag.VOICE_STATE (missing GatewayIntent.GUILD_VOICE_STATES)
[main] WARN JDA - You can manually disable these flags to remove this warning by using disableCache(CacheFlag.VOICE_STATE) on your JDABuilder
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation MDCAdapter implementation.
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#no_static_mdc_binder for further details.
[main] INFO JDA - Login Successful!
[JDA MainWS-WriteThread] INFO WebSocketClient - Connected to WebSocket
[JDA MainWS-ReadThread] INFO JDA - Finished Loading!
```

Comment: Is the bot online? Do you receive any exception?

Comment: @dan1st The bot is online yes! Well on DND because of the activity. I'll update the above text to have the output in the console now.

Comment: You have DIRECT_MESSAGES and no GUILD_MESSAGES so it will only see messages in DMs.

Comment: @Minn Yep, you were right! That's why I like to send everything it's always the simple stuff! Thank you very much!!